# VBA работа с массивом в словаре

Tags: массивы, excel, vba, словари

Добрый день, вопрос думаю весьма простой для профессионалов, но сам я зелен и не могу допереть.
Есть словарь и в каждом значение этого словаря есть одномерный Integer массив.

```
Dim someDicri   
Set someDicri = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

Dim someArr()   
ReDim SomeArr(1)
someArr(0) = 6
someArr(1) = 4

someDicri.Add "someKey", someArr
```

Как мне получить доступ к элементу массива по ключу словаря не создавая дополнительных переменных и присваивания им значения словаря?
Такие варианты выдают ошибку.

```
someDicri.Item("someKey").(0)
someDicri.Item("someKey").someArr(0)
```

И как мне потом перебрать этот массив по ключу. Самое главное без создания дополнительных переменных.

```
Dim noname
Set noname = someDicri.Item("someKey")
Debug.Print noname(0)
```

Эт я конечно могу но блин мне кажется это настолько дурным тоном.

Comment: Откуда такое условие - *без создания дополнительных переменных* ???

Comment: Как раз таки дополнительные правильно названные переменные улучшат читаемость кода.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Точка у тебя лишняя... someDicri.Item("someKey") есть массив, а между массивом и скобками, в которых указываешь индекс, не ставится точка

```
Debug.Print someDicri.Item("someKey")(0)
```

> как получить размер этого массива в значение ключа?

Например, так:

```
someDicri.Add "someKey " & LBound(someArr) & "-" & UBound(someArr), someArr
```

Comment: А не подскажите как получить размер этого массива в значение ключа?

Comment: Что такое "размер массива" в текущем понимании? Если, например, количество элементов - как обеспечена уникальность этого значения? Ведь два элемента с одним и тем же ключом в коллекции как бы не бывает...

Comment: Ну у нас есть элемент словаря и у этого уникального элемента есть массив в значении. Хочется узнать количество элементов в этом одномерном массиве.

Comment: Грасиас! Извиняюсь за столь примитивные вопросы.

Comment: Вот только выбирать элемент по ТАКОМУ ключу будет проблемненько...